# vba looping FOR between two sheets

Tags: vba, excel

So I've this challenge. But first a little information for you: p goes from 1 to 24.

When p is 1 and Cells(X,4)>0 then I want to store all the values when this is true (it might be true several times, while it loops down the 2000 rows) into a value in Worksheets("myvalues").Cells(**6**,11).Value = a.

After this, I want p to be 2 and then do the same, and store the sum of these into Worksheets("myvalues").Cells(**7**,11).Value = a.

And so on until p is 24 (incl. 24)

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rowshift As Integer
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Integer, p as Integer

For x = 2 To 2000

If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 2) = p And Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 4) > 0 Then
    a = a+ Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 5)

p=p+1

End If

For rowshift = 6 to 29

Worksheets("myvalues").Cells(rowshift, 11).Value = a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this do what you intend?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim Spike As Double
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    TargetRow = 6
    For p = 1 To 24
        For R = 2 To 2000
            With Worksheets("DATA").Rows(R)
                If (.Cells(2).Value = p) And (.Cells(4).Value > 0) Then
                    Spike = Spike + .Cells(5).Value
                End If
            End With
        Next R
        Worksheets("MyValues").Cells(TargetRow, 11).Value = Spike
        Spike = 0
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
    Next p
End Sub
```

Comment: @ YowE3K That is correct. I forgot to add the counter for `TargetRow` and have rectified this omission. However, I think your solution is better than mine (looping 6 to 29).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the equivalent of Excel's formula

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$E$2:$E$2000,Data!$B$2:$B$2000,ROW()-5,Data!$D$‌​2:$D$2000,">0")
```

using VBA, I suggest you change your code to have a loop within a loop

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim rowshift As Long
    Dim a As Double

    For rowshift = 6 to 29
        a = 0
        For x = 2 To 2000
            If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 2) = rowshift - 5 And _
               Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 4) > 0 Then
                a = a + Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 5)
            End If
        Next
        Worksheets("myvalues").Cells(rowshift, 11).Value = a
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set p value.
Please try this full code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rowshift As Integer
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Integer, p as Integer


    p = 1
    For x = 2 To 2000
        a = 0
        If p < 25 Then
           If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 2) = p And Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 4) > 0 Then
               a = a+ Worksheets("DATA").Cells(x, 5)    
               p=p+1
           End If
        End If

        If a > 0 Then
            For rowshift = 6 to 29    
                Worksheets("myvalues").Cells(rowshift, 11).Value = a
            Next rowshift
        End If
   Next x
```